# derivative with non integer (irrational) as power

Tags: derivatives, binomial-theorem

How do you prove the power rule can be applied for the derivative of $$x^\pi?$$Since the power is an irrational number, how to use the binomial theorem in this case ?

Comment: How do you _define_ $x^\pi$? The solution necessarily begins there.

Comment: $\frac {\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx} x^n=nx^{n-1}$

Comment: E.g. https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Power_Rule_for_Derivatives#Proof_for_Real_Number_Index

Answer (score 2):

You can use the chain rule and the following trick :

$$x^n=e^{\ln(x)\cdot n}$$

Which has derivate

$$e^{\ln(x)\cdot n}\cdot \frac{n}{x}=n\cdot x^{n-1}$$

for every real $\ n\ $ and positive $\ x\ $

Answer (score 2):

As arthur mentioned in the comments, you first have to define what the symbol $x^y$ means when $x>0$, and $y \in \mathbb{R}$ (regardless of irrational or not). One typical approach is to first define the logarithm and exponential function, prove a bunch of their properties, and AFTER THAT DEFINE $x^y = e^{y \log(x)}$. Then you can prove that 
\begin{equation}
\dfrac{d}{dx}(x^y) = y \cdot x^{y-1}
\end{equation}

Notice the logic of how things progressed: first, define what the symbol $x^y$ is supposed to mean. Then, prove a bunch of properties which are relevant such as:
\begin{align}
x^y \cdot x^z = x^{y+z} \tag{*}
\end{align}
Finally, deduce the differentiation rule as a simple corollary. The toughest part of all this is DEFINING $x^y$. For more information about the details, I highly suggest reading Michael Spivak's book: Calculus, Chapter 18 which is on logarithm and exponential function.

---

Anyway, here's a proof (all these equal signs need to be carefully justified, and for that you should read the book I suggested, or something else)
\begin{align}
\dfrac{d}{dx}(x^y) &= \dfrac{d}{dx}(e^{y \log(x)}) \tag{by definition} \\
&= y \cdot \dfrac{d(\log(x))}{dx} \cdot e^{y \log(x)} \tag{chain rule} \\
&= y \cdot \dfrac{1}{x} \cdot x^y \tag{property of $\log$ and $e$} \\
&= y \cdot x^{y-1} \tag{by (*)}
\end{align}

Comment: Oh another thing which needs to be verified is that this new definition of $x^y$ coincides with the old one when $y$ is rational. I believe these details are taken care of in Spivak's book

Answer (score 0):

Let $y=x^\pi$

$$\ln y = \pi \ln x$$
$$\implies\ln y = \pi \ln x$$
$$\implies\frac{d\,y}{y} = \pi \frac{d \,x}{x}$$
$$\implies\frac{d\,y}{d\,x} = \pi \frac{y}{x} = \pi x^{\pi-1}$$

Coming back to your question the binomial theorem applies even for [irrational indices](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2066300/why-is-the-binomial-expansion-not-valid-for-an-irrational-index)

So you can us the binomial expansion to prove it as well.